# Trying to display the response on webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to display the output on my webpage but i can get the below

> Err: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Suppose i am writing `console.log(name)` here I can the response in command prompt but if i am writing `res.send(name)` then I can get the above Error

please tell me where i can set the headers and give a suggestion best online nodejs editors

Thanks in advance....

```
app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    const name = [{
        Name : 'Pavan',
        age : 26
    },{
        Name : 'kumar',
        age : 27
    }]

    for (let index = 0; index < name.length; index++) {
        const element = name[index];
        // res.send(name[index].Name);        
        console.log(name[index].Name);        
    }

});
```

Comment: This happens when response was delivered to client and again you are trying to give response. As You are doing it in for loop

Answer (score 0):

You need to join them together and send them all at once:

```
const names = name.map(({ Name }) => Name).join("<br>");
res.send(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write res.send(), the response will be sent to the client. When you write the statement in for loop, you are trying to send multiple responses to the same request which is not possible. So, instead of writing res.send in for loop, create an array and push the data to the array and write res.send outside of the loop with the array.

Answer (score 0):

`res.send()` can be use only once , after that you will get

> [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the
>   client

means you can only one time send response to request

if you want to send names to response , you should do like this :

```
app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    const name = [{
        Name : 'Pavan',
        age : 26
    },{
        Name : 'kumar',
        age : 27
    }]

    /*for (let index = 0; index < name.length; index++) {
        const element = name[index];       
        console.log(name[index].Name);        
    }*/

    let onlyNames=name.map((item)=>{return item.Name+"<br/>"});
    res.send(onlyNames); 
});
```